# What is the difference between theta-role, theta-grid and argument?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics

I know that theta-role has the distinctions like agent, theme, goal, etc., but all of them refer to entity, right? And argument can refer to both entity and sentence? Could you please explain them as well as theta-grid with some examples? And one more question is, I know that verb assigns theta-roles, but does noun also assign any theta-roles to other constituents?

Comment: Haegeman 1994 *Introduction to Government and Binding Theory* : Q1. What is an argument? p. 44 (para 1) Q2. What is a theta (or thematic) role? pp. 49-50 Q3. What is a theta-grid? p. 51

Comment: Also, there is a lot of stuff online, e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Government_and_Binding_Theory/Theta_Theory

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! But may I confirm something? It is predicate (not only verb) that assigns theta-roles right? @Alex B